# Arcmap - raster positioning on the map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, netcdf

I work in Arcmap 10.3.1.

I have raster dataset - spatial reference **3413**

[image]

My problem is that I can not send this data on a map.

*Sequence*:

1. Add raster dataset
2. Add basemap
   [image]

**How do I display the data on the card in the correct projection?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be too obvious, but your screenshot indicates that the layer you are trying to display is beneath the basemap in the TOC. Try to move it above the basemap to display it.

- Further, do you need to use the AGO Basemap for your purposes?
- Does the raster initially display correctly, before adding the
  basemap?
- Do you get any Geographic Transformation warnings?
- Are you certain the indicated projection for your raster is correct? Have you checked the metadata? Sometimes people "assume" a projection and define it on a dataset, without further checking with the data originator. You don't give many details about the data, so I'm not sure if this could have happened somewhere along the way.